# ¿Es lo mismo decir "El tiempo es 'el' que es" que "El tiempo es 'lo' que es"?

Tags: gramática, pronombres, clíticos

En la siguiente frase:

> El tiempo es **el** que es

¿sería tambien correcto decir lo siguiente?

> El tiempo es **lo** que es

¿Tienen las dos frases el mismo significado o hay alguna diferencia?

La primera frase viene de la serie "El Ministerio del Tiempo". ¿Podíamos usar la segunda en el mismo contexto?

Answer (score 4):

Ambas son correctas y ambas tienen significados diferentes

> El tiempo es **lo** que es

Aquí se hace alusión al **significado**

- *Una mesa es **lo** que es... Cuatro patas y una superficie plana sobre ellas*.
- *El tiempo es **lo** que es, una una magnitud física con la que medimos la duración de acontecimientos....*

> El tiempo es **el** que es

Aquí se alude al **significante**

- *Esta mesa es **la** que tenemos, y no otra*.
- *El tiempo es **el** que es, esta lloviendo y hace frío, hay que aguantarse*.

Answer (score 2):

No son intercambiables. En la primera frase:

> El tiempo es **el** que es.

"El" hace referencia al propio tiempo. El sentido de la frase implica que el tiempo es invariable, que el tiempo que existe es el que existe y no se puede modificar.

Para la segunda frase, invocaré el título de otro programa de televisión, de hace algún tiempo. Supongamos la frase:

> El tiempo es oro.

Si dices "el tiempo es **lo** que es", "lo" haría referencia a aquello con lo que estás calificando el tiempo, que en la frase de ejemplo sería el "oro".

En todo caso, esta segunda frase no me termina de sonar natural, sino más bien algo forzada. Yo usaría la frase "el tiempo es como es".

Comment: O bien "el tiempo es así", o "tal como es".

Comment: ¿Es posible que la frase pudiera significar algo como "el tiempo es el presente" (y no el futuro)? Aqui esta la frase en el guion original. 

**JULIAN: Ahora mismo puedo imaginarme cualquier
cosa… (Se lo piensa) ¿Se puede viajar
al futuro?
SALVADOR: 
No: el tiempo es el que es, joven.** Tambien he visto la forma "el tiempo es el que es y el que fue".